# xpath:how to find a node that not contains text?

Tags: xpath

I have a html like:

```
...
<div class="grid">
    "abc"
    <span class="searchMatch">def</span>
</div>
<div class="grid">
    <span class="searchMatch">def</span>
</div>
...
```

I want to get the div which not contains text,but xpath

```
//div[@class='grid' and text()='']
```

seems doesn't work,and if I don't know the text that other divs have,how can I find the node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's suppose I have inferred the requirement correctly as:

Find all `<div>` elements with `@class='grid'` that have no directly-contained non-whitespace text content, i.e. no non-whitespace text content unless it's within a child element like a `<span>`.

Then the answer to this is

```
//div[@class='grid' and not(text()[normalize-space(.)])]
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a [`not()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/not) statement + [`normalize-space()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/normalize-space) :

```
//div[@class='grid' and not(normalize-space(text()))]
```

or

```
//div[@class='grid' and normalize-space(text())='']
```

Comment: Just to explain why: your code `text()=''` will only succeed if there is a text node and it is zero-length. But in the normal course of things, zero-length text nodes never exist: you actually want to test for the absence of a text node.

Comment: Actually, I think this answer is wrong. Try it on `<div><span>x</span>content</div>`. If there are two text nodes, (one before the span and one after), and the second text node (after the span) is not all-white, then in XPath 1.0 normalize-space(text()) will ignore the second text node, while in XPath 2.0 it will throw an error. I think you want `and not(text()[normalize-space(.)])`

Comment: @MichaelKay OP has provided specific source code with only one non-empty child text node `"abc"`. He didn't ask about condition *If there are two text nodes*, so solution is correct for this specific case

Comment: It's always a problem to infer requirements from one example, but (s)he did say the HTML was "like" this one, and (s)he wanted a "div which not contains text", so I think you have to generalize a little from the example.

Comment: @MichaelKay , your XPath can be applied for more general cases, so please add your own answer, so OP can accept it. However, I don't think that my answer can be interpreted as "wrong" and should be downvoted...